# i use nebular for my angular app, but i want change some css manually and i can't do it

Tags: css, angular, nebular

i use nebular for my angular app, but i want change some `css` manually and i can't do it.
for example in using `nb-select` or `nb-toggle` i can't change `css` as i want.
have you any idea to help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llllW.png)
for example this is a `nb-select`, that i want to define `disply`, `position` and `width` with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution that resolve my problem. I use `ng-deep`.
in my case I solve my problem by below solution:

```css
nb-select {
        ::ng-deep {
          button.select-button {
            border: 1px solid #e0e0e0 !important;
            padding-right: 1.25rem !important;
            padding-left: 2.2rem !important;
            min-width: 8rem;
            height: 40px;
          }
        }
      }
```